# what is the difference between "//div[.//a[text()='SELENIUM']]" and "//div[//a[text()='SELENIUM']]" in selenium xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

what is the difference between "//div[.//a[text()='SELENIUM']]" and "//div[//a[text()='SELENIUM']]" in selenium xpath.

Can some one please clarify my query on xpath, what is the difference when i give dot(.) before //a and without dot(.) .//a

you can use the above mentioned xpath's in this url "http://demo.guru99.com/selenium/guru99home/" to see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//x` searches the whole tree

`.//x` searches the subtree under the context node

So in a predicate, `//div[//x]` selects a `div` if there is an `x` anywhere in the document, while `//div[.//x]` selects a `div` if there is an `x` within the subtree rooted at that `div`.

Comment: Thanks Michael Kay, now i got it.